# How to pass variables into Blade using Laravel's Mail functions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I have this class that takes care of emails.

```
public function mail($emails, $message)
    {

        Mail::queue('emails.notification', ['message' => $message], function($m) use ($emails) {
            $m->to($emails);
            $m->subject('Notification....');

        });
    }
```

the $massage parameter is called from the a this class,

```
private function report(Notification $notification, $resCode)
    {
        if(empty($resCode)){
            $resCode = "no response found";
        }

        $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is down' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
             $notification->slack_channel);

        $this->reporter->mail($notification->email,$notification->website_url.' is down '. ' this is the status Code: '. $resCode);


    }
```

Now i want to display the message the message in the emails.notification.blade and i tried this way

```
@extends('layout')
@section('header')
@stop
@section('content')
        <h1>The Web site is down!</h1>
               {{ $message }}


@stop
@section('footer')
@stop


  [ErrorException]
  htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

this is the exception that I got. anyone with a better suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, the variables are passed as an associative array to `Mail::send()`:

```php
$data = ['emailId' => $emailId, 'mailBody' => $mailBody];
    
Mail::send(
    'mail.emailForgotPassword',
    $data,
    function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('xyz.com', 'abc');
        $message->to($data['emailId'])->subject('Your Subject');
    }
);
```

and in your Blade template, you can reference the variables by using `{{$mailBody}}` or `{{$emailId}}` .

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Sending Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail), you can pass variable value in array form as second param.

```
Mail::send('templatepath', 'blade-variable', function($m) use($user){
     $m->from('from@domain.com', 'From Label');
     $m->to('to@domain.com', 'To Label')->subject('Subject');
});
```

Here *blade-variable* is a second parameter. You can replace you array value with this same.

Further, as from your placed error *htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given*. Means that `$message` variable is not the string. Check `$message` value and pass string like: `['message' => 'This is the message..!']`

Hope this will clear your doubt!

Comment: that is the challenge that I have. Because the message is coming from an http request, it has website URL and status code. it is ab object. changing it into a string is the challenge.

Comment: Very simple..! Replace below code to you mail blade: `<?php
print('<pre style="color:red;">');
print_r($message);
print('</pre>');
?>`

Answer (score 0):

This Follow [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail)

```
$info = array('firstname'=>'xyz','lastname'=>$lastname);
Mail::queue('emails.notification', ['message' => $info], function($m) use ($emails) {
        $m->to($emails);
        $m->subject('Notification....');

    });
```

view page print

```
{{ $message }}
```